# Rewrite the program making use of an array instead of 5 variables 'age'

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function

(i) Rewrite the program making use of an array instead of 5 variable 'age'
(ii) Re write the program making use of sub routine and functions. One sub routine will ask for all the inputs. A function will receive the inputs as parameters, calculate the average, and return the answer. The second sub routine will display as answer.

Program:

```
Dim age1, age2, age3, age4, age5 As Integer
Dim average As Double

average = 0

age1 = InputBox("Enter age:")
age2 = InputBox("Enter age:")
age3 = InputBox("Enter age:")
age4 = InputBox("Enter age:")
age5 = InputBox("Enter age:")

average = (age1+age2+age3+age4+age5) / 5

MsgBox("Average age is " & average)
```

Is my answer correct?

```
Dim age (5)  As Integer
Dim sum, average as Double

average = 0 

For i as Integer 0 - 5

Next 

average = sum/5

MsgBox ("Average age is " & average)
```

Comment: We are not here to do your assignments for you.  The point is for *you* to learn which doesn't happen if we do your work.   From whats there it looks like you havent tried much.  Start by turning on Option Strict because `InputBox` does not return an integer

Comment: What is wrong in my answer?

Dim age (5)  As Integer
Dim average as Double

 average = 0 

For i as Integer 0 - 5
lstBox.Items.Add(age))

Next

Comment: Dont be coy, your answer was not in the original post.  As for what's wrong, no Subs and no Functions as the assignment calls for.  Not sure what use the ListBox is or how data gets into the array

Comment: So much of insult for asking an answer for a question for it might appear in the exams and time is limited since I was too busy completing my dissertation. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anyone insulting you, but the answer is no, it is not correct.

Comment: Glad if someone can explain as well.

Comment: I already explained: the assignment calls for `making use of sub routine and functions` to do certain things.  Your answer lacks those, nor does it show how the user input gets into the array.

Comment: Please check my answer above. I read some notes before writing it. I am not sure where the mistake is.

Comment: This is not a tutorial site.  It is meant for answers to specific questions, not mentoring or step by step hand holding. As for whats wrong this time, there is no code in the loop so it does nothing; it wont compile because of syntax errors.  Paste it into VB and the IDE will tell you whats wrong.

Comment: Our policy about [homeworks](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: When is this due?

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes, but the first to come to my mind is with the array. Array indexes by default start at 0, and when defining an array in VB.Net you give it the index of the last element. Therefore an array defined as `Dim age(5) As Integer` has positions `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5`. Count em up, and that's **six** total elements.

Additionally, the problem specifically asks for you to use functions, none of which are shown or defined here, and your sample never actually calculates the average. When it does, you are supposed to return the value rather than add elements to a ListBox or other control.

More help than this, and I feel like I'd be doing you a dis-service. The point of the exercise seems to be giving you practice at doing this stuff yourself.

---

Updating the original, since the OP seems to have trouble even understanding what is required of her.

This is an assignment, and as is often the case for school assignments, there are *artificial constraints*. It may be perfectly possible — even easier — to solve the problem without using Functions or arrays, but to do so would still result in failing the objective for the assignment. The *first step* in this assignment is to define the array and methods mentioned in the requirements. You need two functions with signatures that look something like this:

```
Public Function GetInput() As Int()
   '...
End Function
```

and

```
Public Function GetAverage(ByVal ages() As Integer) As Double
   '...
End Function
```

And then you need to update your program to actually call these new methods. Implementing those two functions and the code that calls them are still up to the OP. But getting the functions into the code is the very first thing to do here, and it seems like the OP just hasn't understood this.

Comment: Dim age (5)  As Integer
Dim sum, average as Double

average = 0 

For i as Integer 0 - 5

Next 

average = sum/5

MsgBox (“Average age is “ & average)

Comment: Please check my answer above. I read some notes before writing it. I am not sure where the mistake is.

Comment: Don't use `MsgBox()`! Declare a `Function` and use `Return` to send the result back to the main program. Unless you do this, you'll **fail** the assignment, even if you produce the right value.

Answer (score 0):

In truth the answer to your question is NO...

But you ARE close...

Keep trying. You will figure it out.

You will know when you have it "right" then it gives you the right answer, though I am assuming you have access to the development tools... which, for homework.. is a BIG ASSUMPTION.

If you don't, might I suggest you make a table in excel or on paper like the following...

[image]

It shows a list of the variables you will use across the top and the step time down the left.

Now manually follow you code for each step and enter the values of the variables as you go or as they change.

IF you come up with the right answer at the end..

Assuming there are no glaring syntax errors, YOU PROBABLY GOT IT RIGHT.